# Utilizing Both Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, windows

ok so my current OS on my laptop is Windows 10 Pro. if i was to download and install Ubuntu on my laptop, would i have the option to be able to switch back and forth with both Operating Systems?

Comment: Do you mean "switch back and forth" without rebooting? Or do you mean using WSL? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: or do you mean dual boot one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

To switch back and forth without rebooting, the only way is through a Virtual Machine.   When you dual boot, you have to reboot to switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

You can use a dual OS system meaning installing Ubunutu as your secondary OS. You will be able to switch between your windows OS and Ubuntu OS while booting up. As a secondary option, you can go for installing a VM (Virtual Machine) such as VMware or Virtual Box to run Ubuntu within Windows. The latter is a great option if you wish to use the OS without many issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would be able to, glad to hear you're interested! There are two ways of doing this, having a Live USB which allows you to test it out without installing it on your hard drive.

Or you could dual boot, and have some of your hard drive allocated to windows, and some of it allocated to ubuntu.

Hope you enjoy it!